# A good example for using HMM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gesture-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I want to do hand gesture recognition with hmm in matlab. I studied the theoretical materials in both hmm concept and hmm in mathwork . But I need to see some real examples which uses matlab instructions for dealing with hmm. I searched in the web but could not find a good one. Does any one know a reference which uses matlab instructions in a hmm process?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the toolbox by K. Murphy and [its tutorial](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/HMM/hmm_usage.html).

The built-in hmm functions in Matlab are pretty limited I find (though I did not use the very last edition of Matlab). However you can look at the [Matlab tutorial](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hidden-markov-models-hmm.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) too.

Finally, you can check [this toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55866-hidden-markov-model-toolbox--hmm-). It contains a demo file.

On a side note, be aware that your question is somewhat off-topic here. Adding some code to show that you a least tried something and clearly spot what is causing you trouble (training the model? formatting the data? applying the Viterbi algorithm?) would make this question much more interesting to the community.